# What extensions affect the fingerprint ja3?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Many articles mention that the ja3 fingerprint depends on extensions. For example,

https://engineering.salesforce.com/tls-fingerprinting-with-ja3-and-ja3s-247362855967/

Where can I find a list of extensions that affect the fingerprint?

[image: dump from wireshark]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All extensions affect ja3.

Details: https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-avoid-web-scraping-blocking-tls/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).